# Jquery animate n times?

Tags: jquery, loops, slider

I have a slider that when clicked, animates a div vertically, then goes back to the same position as when started.

http://www.eirestudio.net/hosting-files/markup/

My question is; how can I make this slider slide n times, let's say 10 instead of just once?

**JavaScript**

```
$('#featured li.block div').click(function()
{
    $(this).animate
    ({
        top: "-=200"
    }, 300, function() 
    {
        $(this).css('top', '220px').animate
        ({
            top: "-=220"
        }, 300 );
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="featured">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li class="block">
                <div>aaa</div>
            </li>
            <li class="block">
                aaa
            </li>
            <li class="block">
                aaa
            </li>
            <li class="block">
                aaa
            </li>
            <li class="block">
                aaa
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare a function inside of your click event that calls back to itself to handle the looping of your animation.

```
$('#featured li.block div').click(function() {
    var f = function($this, count) {
        $this.animate({
            top: "-=200"
        }, 300, function() {
            $this.css('top', '220px').animate({
                top: "-=220"
            }, 300, function() {
                if (count > 0) {
                    count = count - 1;
                    f($this, count);
                }
            });
        });
    };
    f($(this), 10);
});
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/4tKBF/4/) with the css provided.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is by binding the behavior to a custom event, then triggering that event recursively as you decrement a counter:

```
$('#featured li.block div').click(function() {
  var times = 10;
  $(this).bind('roll', function(){ // bind custom event
    $(this).animate({
       top: "-=200"
     }, 300, function() {
       $(this).css('top', '220px').animate({
         top: "-=220"
       }, 300, function() { // add callback function here
         if (--times) {
           $(this).trigger('roll'); // trigger custom event
         }
       });
    });
  }).trigger('roll'); // first trigger to start the process
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/redler/Nnt3j/

Comment: Woah, closet yet! Thanks Ken, could this integrated with the easing plugin easily to make the div start slowly, the faster, then again slowly and stop?

Comment: @Keith, if you want the easing to affect all ten animations as a unit, that's a much more complex undertaking. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Ah I suppose yeah, it's no biggie though. Would be nice but so thankful for what you have given me already!

Comment: @Keith -- here's an idea: Check the `times` counter, and set your animation speed based on its distance from 5. So perhaps something like `speed = 100+(abs(times-5)*60)`. You'd get a range of speeds from 100 to 400, fast->slow->fast.

Comment: No probs, will do, thanks again. Also, http://jsfiddle.net/redler/Nnt3j/ - when clicked again after first loop, the div never comes back :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to chain successive `.animate` calls using `queue: true`, which will animate each one after the preceding animation completes. Eg.:

```
$(this).animate( { top: "-=200"" }, { queue: true, duration: 3000 })
  .animate( { top: "-=200"" }, { queue: true, duration: 3000 })
  .animate( { top: "-=200"" }, { queue: true, duration: 3000 });
// And so on.
```

A more elegant solution would be to create your own $.fn method...

Comment: Thanks Stef. An extra few quotation marks added, but with those fixed, the animation doesn't visibley loop over and over , just keeps going till it reaches 600px